# How to set texture as active texture for projection painting on an object with multiple materials, and multiple textures that make up each material?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I am using Blender 2.83 and
I am working with a model that I unfortunately cannot share so please bear with me. The model is a character model and I am trying to make updates to the diffuse base color texture on the face.
The face has 3 materials on it. The first is a shader with a large node-graph with all of the usual image textures like a diffuse map, roughness, SSS, and normal maps all weaved together into different math, color, and mix shaders. the second two are smaller shaders for hair (taking up the proceeding two slots).

My issue is this,
If I open up the image editor window and open the diffuse texture, if I make changes to the 2d image, those changes appear in the viewport as expected. If I have the model selected in the 3d viewport, toggle to texture paint mode,  and start painting there ( say drawing white lines directly on the model in the 3d viewport) the model does change, but the image texture in the image editor does not change to reflect my brush strokes.

In the past, with other character models I have worked with, this was not the case, and changes made in the 3d viewport would be reflected back onto my 2d texture open in the image editor. I am curious what the issue could be, and how Blender knows which image I want to paint on when painting in the 3d viewport?

Any suggestions or insights?

Thank you

Comment: Make sure you have the correct image texture selected in your Texture Slots panel before painting - this will inadvertently mess you up if one is selected but then your intent was to paint on a second.

Comment: This solved it for me, thank you!